# Using external variable name within new variable name VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables

Just been trying to solve a problem with fetching a specific from a structure based on another variable name...

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Testing As Test
    ReDim Testing.A(15), Testing.B(13), Testing.C(10)

    Dim Letter As String = Console.ReadLine() 'User Inputs A, B Or C

    Testing.Letter(3) = "XXXXX" 'Selects the array of the letter the user has input from the Letter variable

End Sub

Structure Test
    <VBFixedString(5)> <VBFixedArray(15)> Dim A() As Integer
    <VBFixedString(5)> <VBFixedArray(13)> Dim B() As Integer
    <VBFixedString(5)> <VBFixedArray(10)> Dim C() As Integer
End Structure
```

Thanks for looking and any solutions suggested, its much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but maybe you want a select case statement?

```
Sub Main()

    Dim Testing As Test
    ReDim Testing.A(15), Testing.B(13), Testing.C(10)

    Dim Letter As String = Console.ReadLine() 'User Inputs A, B Or C

    Select Case Letter.ToUpper
    Case "A" : Testing.A(3) = "XXXXX" 
    Case "B" : Testing.B(3) = "XXXXX" 
    Case "C" : Testing.C(3) = "XXXXX" 
    End Select

End Sub
```

You could also use reflection...

Comment: Derek, although it wasn't specifically what I was asking it is a good solution to my problem. Thank you!